# Azure Devops project endpoint and SQL credentials

Tags: azure-devops

I have create a DevOps project service in the Azure portal.

I have chosen ASP.NET Core, SQL database, and Virtual Machine deployment.

This generates a project on `dev.azure.com` and a pipeline.

This pipeline generates some resources:

- Virtual Machine

  - Storage account
  - SQL Server
  - SQL Database
  - ...

My questions are:

- Where is the application endpoint? I have try to browse the sample project from VM public ip address but it does not work.
- How can I connect to my SQL database? I have chosen a database administrator user name during project creation, but I did not choose a password. Where is this password?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where is the application endpoint? I have try to browse the sample
>   project from VM public ip address but it does not work.

In Azure Web portal, navigate to the page of your Devops Starter. For me,  I use `.net`+ `Windows Web app` combination. And I can simply find the Application endpoint here:

[image]

Ps: Not sure if it also works for your project.

> How can I connect to my SQL database? I have chosen a database
>   administrator user name during project creation, but I did not choose
>   a password. Where is this password?

DevOps Starter sets up a **random** SQL password and uses it for the release pipeline. To reset the password and connect to the Azure SQL database you can check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops-project/azure-devops-project-sql-database?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops-project%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json#connect-to-the-azure-sql-database):

- On the DevOps Starter dashboard, select SQL Database to go to the management page for the SQL database.
- Select Set server firewall, and then select Add client IP.
- Select Save. Your client IP now has access to the SQL Server Azure resource.
- Go back to the SQL Database pane.
- At the right, select the server name to navigate to the configuration page for SQL Server.
- Select Reset password, enter a password for the SQL Server admin login, and then select Save. Be sure to keep this password to use later in this tutorial.

*You may now optionally use client tools such as SQL Server Management Studio or Visual Studio to connect to SQL Server and the Azure SQL database. Use the Server name property to connect.*

*If you didn't change the database username when you initially configured the project in DevOps Projects, your username is the local part of your email address. For example, if your email address is johndoe@microsoft.com, your username is johndoe.*